# SPARQL Query for all Books by George Orwell

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I created this query to return all books that are notable works by George Orwell but it returns no result.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?name ?title where {
   ?person foaf:name ?name .
   ?title dbo:author ?person .
   ?title dbo:notableWork dbp:George_Orwell .
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why there is no result.

I am running the query in http://dbpedia.org/snorql

Comment: I think your request for the author of a notable work by :George_Orwell is a little silly, but maybe this is the starting point for something more sophisticated?

Comment: @MarkMiller yes, this query is silly but I am trying to find an example to describe all of George Orwell's books by something else (like by finding all British Satirical Novels).

Comment: sounds good.  have fun!  I added some ideas for your detective work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have the triples about notable works in the wrong order?

Try rewriting based on this working query

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
:George_Orwell dbo:notableWork ?title 
}
```

.

```
title
:Nineteen_Eighty-Four
:Animal_Farm
```

You can also bind :George_Orwell to a variable and ask more about that:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
values ?author { :George_Orwell } .
?author rdfs:label ?l .
?title ?p ?author .
?title rdf:type  dbo:Book .
filter (lang(?l) = "en")
}
```

and DESCRIBE things

```
describe :Animal_Farm
```

Comment: `select * { ?s dct:subject dbc:Books_by_George_Orwell}` Never forget the "power" of the Wikipedia categories :D